# How to show a chart or visualization on Alexa Echo Show?

Tags: visualization, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

There are several Alexa skills that include charts - CNBC's Alexa skill is even highlighting the fact that their integration with the Alexa Presentation Language (APL) allows users to view charts:

> Now with APL integration, the CNBC skill can do more on your favorite Alexa devices. Visualize market movements with charts, see a market snapshot, watch the latest videos from CNBC, and more!

Yet I can find no documentation or code on Github on how to create such visualizations using the APL. Is CNBC using a beta feature of the APL that is not publicly available at this time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of now, APL is still in beta; and yes, skills with charts means that they are using the beta feature. However, beta is publicly available.

If you wish to build a skill with APL, you need to turn on the `Alexa Presentation Language` and `Display Interface` options in `Interfaces` in the `Custom` section for your skill in the Amazon Developer Console.

Secondly, APL supports only a [set of components](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-component.html), at least for now. Of them, [`Image`](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-image.html) is one, which is the equivalent of HTML's `img` tag. Any visualisation item on the screen—graphs, charts, etc.—can only be and are therefore inherently `Image`. If you observe, such charts are not interactive, or if they are, then they would be wrapped in a [`TouchWrapper`](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-touchwrapper.html) (`onClick`)—leading to another intent. So, they would have a routine batch converting charts into images.

As for building skills with APL, you have two options: one, you may use Alexa Developer Console's APL builder tool, which is also in beta. To access it, click on `Display` in the `Custom` pane. Once built, you can copy the UI's JSON into your source code; two, you can write the UI components directly in your source code pursuant to [APL requirements](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-document.html). You may also build your own parser, if you're feeling adventurous.